# Does Vue 3 support HTML-based single file components without compilation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've been using HTML-based components with Vue 2 - and loading them dynamically, without a compile step. That is, files that look like this:

```
<style scoped>
</style>
<template>
  <div>empty component</div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return {
        };
    },
    async mounted(){
    },
    destroyed: function(){
    },
    methods: {
    },
    components: {
    },
}
</script>
```

and are served statically.

Does this approach still work with Vue 3?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@marcel.leusch/use-vue-3-single-file-components-without-compilation-ac2ccb5f15c2

You need to use the vue3 single file component loader

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[Vue 3 Setup without Build Tools](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools) is the official guide on how to use Vue 3 without build tools. Hope it helps.